# partition the hive data complex data types while inserting data its shows error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

i created a table using hive i want to partition the data  based on location

```
create table student(
      id bigint
     ,name string
     ,location string
     , course array<string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMiTED fields terminated by '\t'
collection items terminated by ','
stored as textfile;
```

and data like

```
100 student1    ongole  java,.net,hadoop
101 student2    hyderabad   .net,hadoop
102 student3    vizag   java,hadoop
103 student4    ongole  .net,hadoop
104 student5    vizag   java,.net
105 student6    ongole  java,.net,hadoop
106 student7    neollre .net,hadoop
```

creating partition table:

```
create table student_partition(
      id bigint
     ,name string
     ,course array<string>)
PARTITIONED BY (address string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMiTED fields terminated by '\t'
collection items terminated by ','
stored as textfile;
```

> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE student_partition PARTITION(address) select *
>   from student;

i'm trying to partition the data based on location but it shows below error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:23 Cannot insert into
>   target table because column number/types are different 'address':
>   Cannot convert column 2 from string to array.

please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of the source and the target should match

---

Option 1: adjust the source to the target. The partition column goes last

```
insert into student_partition partition (address)
select  id,name,course,location
from    student
;
```

Option 2: adjust the target to the source

```
insert into student_partition partition (address) (id,name,address,course)
select  *
from    student
;
```

P.s.
You might need this -

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
;
```